# Multiple nested columns with grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

I can't seem to wrap my head around this.
How do I make [this table](http://plnkr.co/edit/F80TxvYBB6JjAK5WMOWs?p=preview) in the bootstrap grid system?

Here's a regular `table`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">c</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">f</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left side -->
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- 1st column -->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">a</div>
                        <!-- 2nd column -->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">b</div>
                        <!-- colspan 2 -->
                        <div class="col-xs-8">c</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Right side -->
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- 3rd column -->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">d</div>
                        <!-- 4th column -->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">e</div>
                        <!-- colspan 2 -->
                        <div class="col-xs-8">f</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All bootstrap grid rows work off a 12 column layout.  If you use more than 12 columns in a single row, the extra column fields will automatically wrap to the next line. Since the left and right table are both defined as `col-xs-8`, the second one will get bumped to the next line (16 > 12).

Try `col-xs-6` instead:

```html
<!-- Left side -->
<div class="col-xs-6">

<!-- Right side -->
<div class="col-xs-6">
```

When you nest rows, you begin working off a new, inner 12 column layout that is constrained by the parent of your new row class. I'd update your inner rows to use the following:

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- 1st column -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">a</div>
    <!-- 2nd column -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">b</div>
    <!-- colspan 2 -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">c</div>
</div>
```

#### [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/pe7UC/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I can't believe I missed the 8+8 != 12 :D